# Saving datas from one database to another

Tags: python, django

I want to copy the datas from one database to another in Postgres. I wrote a script in django and was able to grab a datas from one specific table but how can i add that data in other database.New database has same table and column name, i want to save that old database files to new database. 
This might be easy for some of you guys but i really couldnt figure that out.

Comment: Is this a one off thing or do you need to do this all time?

Comment: just for once. New datas will be saved in new database automatically

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with either API but if the rows/columns have the same dimmensions you could do something like (and this is partially pseudocode):

```
for x in range(height):
    for y in range(width):
        data = call_data_from_database_A(x, y)
        new_entry = enter_data_into_database_B(x, y)
```

Where the Call_data is you're getting data from that specific row/column, and enter_data enters the data into that specific row/column. I'm not familiar with either API but if you find the two I'm sure you could figure it out rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own import and export code, why not use the native capabilities of Postgres and dump the table from your old database then import it into your new one:

> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: I would definitely use this approach if possible.  Why one would want to use a web framework to handle database copying is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: @jeff.vanvoorst Some people can't see the woods for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this with Django (move one Django database to another, defined with a different model django database) is to write a 2 Django views and one jquery html page.

The first view will be in the original Django app. It will essentially create a json object model of the database and push it out on a get request. This is custom to your Django's models.

The second view will be in the new Django app. This will take in json data and format it to match your current Django database (fields might not match up exactly, hence the reason for doing this migration). You then just add elements into the new database just as you were creating a new Django model entry([example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)).

I personally use a one off jquery html page that gets the json data from the first view and posts it to the second one. You could exclude this piece and just write it all in python in the second view, but I find doing it this way to be much cleaner.